# Customer and branch query in company database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have following four tables in my database :

EMPLOYEE

```
PK: employeeID;     
FK: empBranch references BRANCH;
FK: empSupervisor references EMPLOYEE
```

[image]

BRANCH

```
PK: branchNumber
FK: branchManager references EMPLOYEE
```

[image]

CUSTOMER

```
PK: customerID
```

[image]

ORDERS

```
PK: orderNumber
FK: customerID references CUSTOMER; 
FK: salesPerson references EMPLOYEE
```

[image]

Now I need to list out these two things :

1. The Employee_ID and name of salespersons who have sold only to customers located in the same city as the city in which the salesperson’s branch is located.
2. The Employee_ID and name of salespersons who have sold to every customer located in the same city as the city in which the salesperson’s branch is located.

Please help me to answer both queries

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @marc_s I want simple SQL query

Comment: Have you tried something yet ?

Answer (score 1):

The Employee_ID and name of salespersons who have sold only to customers located in the same city as the city in which the salesperson’s branch is located.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  e.employeeid,
  e.emplname || e.empfname AS salesperson_name
FROM
  orders o
  INNER JOIN customer c ON o.customerid = c.customerid
  INNER JOIN branch b ON o.salesperson = b.branchmanager
  INNER JOIN employee e ON o.salesperson = e.employeeid
WHERE 
  c.custcity = b.branchcity -- salesperson's branch located in the same city as customer
```

Comment: And for second case ?

Comment: Second case is just modifying the first case - do your homework please.

Comment: Will removing where clause serve the purpose for second query ?

Comment: An upvote for encouraging the OP to try something on their own. Stack Overflow is a source of help, but is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't specify a specific RDBMS this is written for SQL server.

1. The Employee_ID and name of salespersons who have sold only to customers located in the same city as the city in which the salesperson’s branch is located.

   ```
   SELECT 
       e.EmployeeID,
       e.Empfname + ' ' + e.Emplname Name

   FROM Orders o
   JOIN customer c 
       ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerId
   JOIN Employee e 
       ON o.SalesPerson = e.Employeeid
   JOIN Branch b
       ON e.EMPBRANCH = b.BranchManager
   GROUP BY e.Employeeid, e.EMPFNAME + ' ' + e.EMPLNAME
   HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN c.custCity <> b.BranchCity THEN 1 END) = 0 -- no sales outside of the employee's city
   ```
2. The Employee_ID and name of salespersons who have sold to every customer located in the same city as the city in which the salesperson’s branch is located.

There are multiple ways to go about getting the count per city, but I used a CTE.

```
    WITH CusPerCity AS     -- get client counts per city
    (
    SELECT
        CustCity,
        COUNT(Distinct c.CustomerId) CustomersPerCity
    FROM Orders o
    JOIN Customer c 
        ON o.customerid = c.customerid
    GROUP BY CustCity
    )   


    SELECT 
        e.EmployeeID,
        e.Empfname + ' ' + e.Emplname Name

    FROM Orders o
    JOIN Customer c 
        ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerId
    JOIN Employee e 
        ON o.SalesPerson = e.Employeeid
    JOIN Branch b
        ON e.EMPBRANCH = b.BranchManager
    JOIN CusPerCity cus 
        ON b.BranchCity = cus.CustCity
    WHERE c.CustCity = b.BranchCity
    GROUP BY e.Employeeid, e.EMPFNAME + ' ' + e.EMPLNAME, CustomersPerCity
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.customerID) = cus.CustomersPerCity --number of unique customers sold to equals then number of customers in a city
```